# Can someone explain how to construct a meaningful interpretation of the Jacobian (and full derivative) of a matrixial mapping?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, jacobian

Many are familiar with $R^n \rightarrow R^m$ mappings, mappings from n-dimensional coordinates to m-dimensional coordinates. Although I still don't entirely understand what it means to take the "derivative" of such a map, I can understand the instructions for calculating the jacobian of any given $R^n \rightarrow R^m$ function which will result in an $R^{m \times n}$ matrix of first partial derivatives.

However, I'm considering a  slightly different and less conventional scenario: maps from $R^n \rightarrow R^{m \times k}$, or that is, maps from n-dimensional coordinates to matrices.

In particular, let's consider $R^2 \rightarrow R^{2 \times 2}$ maps, maps from 2D coordinates to 2x2 matrices. An example of this might be a function

$f(x,y) = \begin{pmatrix} xy & x+y \\  x^2 & y^2-x \end{pmatrix}$.

This leaves a question: ***how do we construct a meaningful analog of a Jacobian*** for these types of mappings, and thus a meaningful concept of a "derivative" for multi-variate matrices, rather than strictly multi-variate vectors?

I suspect the answer involves a rank-3 tensor, which I don't really want to deal with unless the math works out nicely. So, I might work with a sort of trick I've seen mentioned on stackexchange in another thread, though never explained nor proven in any fashion, of re-writing a $2 \times 2$ matrix into the form of a $4 \times 1$ vector.

However, this then results in a $4 \times 2$ Jacobian, and I'm not sure how to work with that or if I'm interpreting that correctly, I have no idea how to proceed or what the formalization is. What does it even mean to calculate a "total derivative" of this map? Is this the correct way to construct a Jacobian of a multi-variate matrix? And now that I've calculated it, what do I do with it to construct a meaningful notion of the "derivative" of the original multi-variate matrix, in a particular direction in the domain space?

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of a map $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ at a point $x \in  \mathbb{R}^2$ is defined to be the linear map $f^\prime (x) : \mathbb{R}^2  \to \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$ that satisfies
$$ f(x+h ) = f(x) + f^\prime (x) h + o(h)$$
using the little o notation.

Let $e_i$ be the vector with a 1 at the $i$-th position and zeros elsewhere. From the above we can compute
$$f^\prime (x) e_i = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{f(x+e_it) -f(x)}{t} = \frac{\partial f}{x_i}(x)$$
which is just the matrix containing all the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to the i-th variable. So in this case (using the notation $x = (x_1, x_2)$)
$$\frac{\partial f}{x_1}(x) = 
\begin{pmatrix} x_2 & 1 \\  2x_1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$\frac{\partial f}{x_2}(x) =\begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 1 \\  0 & 2x_2 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

So in total the Jacobi "matrix" $M_{f^\prime} $ of $f^\prime$ is given by
$$M_{f^\prime} (x)= 
\begin{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} x_2 & 1 \\  2x_1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} & \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 1 \\  0 & 2x_2 \end{pmatrix}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

The same result can be achieved by realizing that the map $\mathrm{vec}: \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2} \to \mathbb{R}^4$ that stacks the columns on each other is linear. Define the map $\tilde{f}: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^4$ by $\tilde{f}(x) = \mathrm{vec} f(x) $. We can compute the usual Jacobi matrix of $\tilde{f}$.

With your example $f$ we have
$$\tilde{f}(x_1,x_2) = 
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 x_2 \\
x_1^2 \\
x_1 +x_2\\
x_2^2-x_1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and so the Jacobi matrix $M_{\tilde{f}^\prime}$ of $\tilde{f}$ is
$$
M_{\tilde{f}^\prime}(x_1,x_2) =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_2 & x_1 \\
2x_1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 \\
-1 &  2x_2
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Because $\mathrm{vec}$ is linear we obtain $f^\prime =\mathrm{vec}^{-1} \tilde{f}^\prime $.
And then for the Jacobi matrices
$ f^\prime(x) e_i = \mathrm{vec}^{-1}\tilde{f}^\prime (x) e_i$ and $\tilde{f}^\prime (x) e_i$ is just the $i$-th column of the Jacobi matrix of $\tilde{f}^\prime$ at $x$.
And therefore
$$ f^\prime(x_1,x_2) e_1 =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_2 &1 \\
2 x_1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and
$$ f^\prime(x_1,x_2) e_2 =
\begin{pmatrix}
x_1 &1 \\
0& 2 x_2 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
since $M_{f^\prime} (x_1,x_2) = (f^\prime(x_1,x_2) e_1 ,  f^\prime(x_1,x_2) e_2) $ we see that this calculation is totally equivalent to the above.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, although I'm still getting confused by what's going on here. You didn't specify it, but I assume you constructed a 2x2x2 matrix, a 3-rank tensor in the middle of your reasoning, is that interpretation correct? That actually seems simpler than stacking all the entries of the vector, but this leaves a mystery: how do you actually multiply this tensor with matrices?

It also looks like you computed the equivalent of the gradient, which somehow resulted from what I assume is the equivalent of the "directional" derivative, except for matrices instead of vectors.

Comment: @RayOfHope Yes $M_{f^\prime}(x)$ is a $2 \times 2 \times 2 $ matrix. I am not sure why you want to multiply $M_{f^\prime}(x)$ with a matrix? To obtain $f^\prime (x) h $ ($h \in \mathbb{R}^2$)  we merely need to "multiply" $M_{f^\prime}(x)$ by $h$ in the obvious way. So in the example we have that $f^\prime (x) h= \begin{pmatrix} x_2 & 1 \\  2x_1 & -1 \end{pmatrix} h_1 +  \begin{pmatrix} x_1 & 1 \\  0 & 2x_2 \end{pmatrix} h_2 $ (where $h=(h_1,h_2)$). The quantities $\frac{\partial f }{x_i}$ can be seen as a generalization of the partial derivative.

Comment: @RayOfHope The constructed $2 \times 2 \times 2 $ matrix $M_{f^\prime}(x)$ is more a generalization of the Jacobi matrix than of the gradient (of which the Jacobi matrix is of course a generalization as well).